# Print tuple list into a standard output 'table'

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have a tuple list `[("hi", 1), ("yo", 2)];` and I want to 'convert' this list into a table using the standard output `print s;` in sml into a table-format.

For example the above tuple list will produce an output such as:

```
------------
| "hi" | 1 |
------------
etc...
------------
```

I have this code but its giving me an error:

```
fun outputTable [] = print "Nothing! \n"
  | outputTable ((hd, n)::tl) =
      print "-----------"
      print "| "^hd^" | "^n^" |"
      print "-----------"
      outputTable tl;
```

Here is the error:

```
stdIn:15.2-17.21 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]  
operator: unit
  in expression:
    (print "-----------") print
stdIn:15.2-17.21 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
operator: string
  in expression:
    " |" outputTable
stdIn:13.5-17.21 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]
expression: string
result type:  unit
in declaration:
    outputTable =
      (fn nil =print "Nothing!"
        | :: (<pat>,<pat>) =<exp^ <exp^ <exp<exp>)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use more than one expression in SML you have to enclose multiple lines in parentheses like so:

```
(expr 1; expr2; ...; exprn);
```

So to fix my error I just used that form for my print lines:

```
fun outputTable [] = []
  | outputTable ((hd, n)::tl) =
      (print "------------------\n";
      print ("| " ^ hd ^ " | " ^ Int.toString(n) ^ " |\n");
      print "-------------------\n";
      outputTable tl);
```